# Neural Network Learning Without Training Values

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, neural-network

I am wondering how to go about training a neural network without providing it with training values. My premise for this is that the neural network(s) will be used on a robot that can receive positive/negative feedback from sensors. IE, in order to train it to roam freely without bumping into things, a positive feedback occurs when no collision sensors or proximity sensors are triggered. A negative feedback occurs when the collision/proximity sensors ARE triggered. How can the neural network be trained using this method?

I am writing this in C++

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporal_difference_learning maybe. I have been using this algorithm for chess.

Comment: Thank you for that, I'm in the process of reading this thesis: http://remi.coulom.free.fr/Thesis/   and it turns out what you just mentioned is utilized in this technique.

Comment: @Damir  why don't you make that an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you describe is called reinforcement learning. It could be applied to neural networks, but does not require them in general. The canonical textbook to read on the subject is [Reinforcement Learning: An Introduction](http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~sutton/book/the-book.html) by Richard Sutton and Andrew Barto. The connection between neural networks and reinforcement learning is explored in a bit more detail in the [PDP Handbook](http://www.stanford.edu/group/pdplab/pdphandbook/) by James McClelland.

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at [SLAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultaneous_localization_and_mapping)?  It's a technique robots can use to navigate an area while simultaneously building up and keeping a map of that area.

Comment: Indeed I have, I discovered it in this PDF: http://rossum.sourceforge.net/papers/Localization/PosPosterv4.pdf   from the Rossum Project (http://rossum.sourceforge.net/)    but thank you for the link, as I had not read more on the subject, not knowing what it was called.